# Domain model to JSON - issue with deep serialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, domain-model

I am using Hibernate 4.1 and Spring 3.1.

Consider the following User class having references to other object including self. All the hibernate mappings I have defined are LAZY so will load the reference objects only when I use them in the jsp or code else where.

```
class User {
  private User createdBy;
  private Department department;
  private Project project;
  .....
  .....
}
```

The problem is when I want to return a JSON representation where it uses reflection to do it and there by does a deep serialization. Below is my controller code.

```
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(int id) {
  User user = [fetch user from service];
  return user;
}
```

Since I have self reference also it goes into infinite loop.

What is the solution to get away with this problem? I know that I need to use DTO pattern where I return a UserDTO instead but how many such methods I create. For example, at one place I need just the basic User attributes, at other place I need User and its Department, at other place I need User with Department and Project.

How many such methods I would need to expose. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: You can create flat structured DTOs for every case with required fields from Emp, Proj and Dep.

Comment: I am using org.codehaus.jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a circular reference and your JSON encoder is not handling it. So, you need to handle it manually.

Creating a DTO as you commented would help. You can implement a Helper with one method for each level of decoding you need.

You could use [`BeanUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to copy each property from one bean to the other.

Another solution (a bit more conceptual) would be:

Implement a kind of decorator for each boundary method and apply [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) over the result. An example you could take [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html)

The *Decoration* occurs more or less like this:

```
public interface Controller {
   User getUser(int id);
}

public class RealController {
   public User getUser(int id) {
      return dao.getUser(id);
   }
}

public class DecoratedController {

   private Controller realController;

   public User getUser(int id) {
      // here you will apply dozer or do it manually creating an object with so deep as you wish
      return flatUserStructure(realController.getUser(id));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to tune Hibernate association loading you can use **fetch join**, please read [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

To avoid issues with deep serialization you can create appropriate DTOs and tune them with some thing like the [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) annotation of the [Jackson Java JSON-processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is composed of two parts:

*JSON custom serialization*: You can use this approach to avoid defining several `UserDTO`s for `User`. However, it still remains that you should probably define the JSON serializer as a bean or a configurable service object such that you can command it what to serialize in different controller method mappings. A good example can be found [here](http://sghill-dev.blogspot.nl/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html).

*Spring configuration*: The next step is configure spring to use your customer JSON serializer. So, when using `@ResponseBody`, Spring will use your custom JSON serializer. Nice examples can be found [here](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html) and [there](http://rwehner.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/2-ways-to-create-json-response-for-ajax-request-in-spring3/).